# Reduce network traffic for Native Client installation from Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-nativeclient

My Chrome app contains three `.nexe` files for `arm, x86-32` and `64-bit` processors. When I install this app from `Chrome web store`, the size of downloaded package is the same as the size of the app containing all `.nexe` files. Is it possible to optimize this network traffic?

My `.nmf` file bundled in the app looks like this:

```
{
  "program": {
    "arm": { "url": "arm.nexe" },
    "x86-32": { "url": "x86_32.nexe" },
    "x86-64": { "url": "x86_64.nexe" }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a platform specific section to your manifest.json. Then the packages will only download the components that are specified for that CPU architecture.

There is documentation for that feature here: https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/distributing#reducing-the-size-of-the-user-download-package

And there is an example in the SDK as well: `examples/tutorial/multi_platform`

To summarize the documentation above:
First create a `_platform_specific` directory in your App package. For each architecture, create a subdirectory with that name:

```
|-- my_app_directory/
|       |-- manifest.json
|       |-- my_app.html
|       |-- my_module.nmf
|       +-- css/
|       +-- images/
|       +-- scripts/
|       |-- _platform_specific/
|       |       |-- x86-64/
|       |       |       |-- my_module_x86_64.nexe
|       |       |-- x86-32/
|       |       |       |-- my_module_x86_32.nexe
|       |       |-- arm/
|       |       |       |-- my_module_arm.nexe
|       |       |-- all/
|       |       |       |-- my_module_x86_64.nexe
|       |       |       |-- my_module_x86_64.nexe
|       |       |       |-- my_module_x86_32.nexe
```

Then in the manifest.json file, specify the location of these directories:

```
...
"platforms": [
    {
      "nacl_arch": "x86-64",
      "sub_package_path": "_platform_specific/x86-64/"
    },
    {
      "nacl_arch": "x86-32",
      "sub_package_path": "_platform_specific/x86-32/"
    },
    {
      "nacl_arch": "arm",
      "sub_package_path": "_platform_specific/arm/"
    },
    {
      "sub_package_path": "_platform_specific/all/"
    }
  ]
```

You'll want your .nmf to point to the location of these nexes. The SDK build system has an option to do all of this for you automatically, I'd suggest using it.